# Are there some free-to-use test methodologies?

Tags: agile, tmap

I would like to extend project portfolio with another testing methodology. I used to use TMAP Next from Sogeti here (http://www.tmap.net/en/tmap-next/downloads/tmap-next-downloads).
Are there some other free-to-use methodologies similar to TMAP Next? Especially agile methodologies are welcome.

Comment: Hi Dee, what problem are you trying to solve? Yes, there are plenty of free-to-use testing methodologies, but why do you want to change, and what do you need to accomplish?

Comment: I agree with testerab. There are no silver-bullets: methodologies that work for large telecomm systems developed in corporations may not work well for startups working on new CRM app for mobile phones.

Comment: what I want to achieve is list of recomendations on what I'm asking. by the way, it can perfectly increase traffic of QA&T Q/A, what should be goal of this beta. So do you know some, please write an answer. You don't? Never mind.

Comment: Dee, both dziecou and I know plenty of answers. Most are going to be totally irrelevant to you. If you can't give us a bit more information, we can't give you good answers - it's a two way thing I'm afraid. Different methodologies suit different situations. It depends what problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: if there is a plenty answers, name at least one. I do not see any. Question narrowed ... and somebody added +1 to the question, so there is an interest.

Comment: Just open the CTAL books from Rex Black or the CTAL Syllabuses, especially the TM material of both. There, you will find a few of methodologies mentioned. But, let me ask what is the advantages of applying a methodology without checking whether it is able to solve the problem or not? The whole should be driven by common sense.